# How to decode a List of Objects and save them using SharedPreference?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, sharedpreferences, bloc

I want to save a list of favourited meals. This is part of my Meal Model. I am using Json Serializable package. I tried to use helper functions as well.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'meal.g.dart';

List<Meal> mealExtFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Meal>.from(jsonDecode(str).map((x) => Meal.fromJson(x)));
String mealExtToJson(List<Meal> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

enum Complexity {
  @JsonValue(203)
  simple,
  @JsonValue(204)
  challenging,
  @JsonValue(205)
  hard,
}

enum Affordability {
  @JsonValue(200)
  affordable,
  @JsonValue(201)
  pricey,
  @JsonValue(202)
  luxurious,
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Meal {
  final String id;
  final List<String> categories;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  final List<String> ingredients;
  final List<String> steps;
  final int duration;
  final Complexity complexity;
  final Affordability affordability;
  final bool isGlutenFree;
  final bool isLactoseFree;
  final bool isVegan;
  final bool isVegetarian;

  const Meal({
    required this.id,
    required this.categories,
    required this.title,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.ingredients,
    required this.steps,
    required this.duration,
    required this.complexity,
    required this.affordability,
    required this.isGlutenFree,
    required this.isLactoseFree,
    required this.isVegan,
    required this.isVegetarian,
  });
  factory Meal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MealFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MealToJson(this);

  
}
```

This is part of my favourite cubit where I am trying to save and load the data using SharedPreference. I am managing to favourite a meal but as soon as I restart the application the state is lost. How can I encode and decode the List of Meal to get a persisted state.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'; import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart'; import 'package:meals_app/models/dummy_data.dart'; import 'package:meals_app/models/meal.dart'; import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart'; part 'favourites_state.dart';

class FavouritesCubit extends Cubit<FavouritesState> {   final String favouriteDataPref = 'favouriteData';   List<Meal> favourites = [];   SharedPreferences? _prefs;   FavouritesCubit() : super(const FavouritesInitial()) {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      _prefs = prefs;
      loadSavedFavourites(prefs);
    });   }

  void toggleFavourite(String newMealId) {
    final existingIndex = favourites.indexWhere((meal) => meal.id == newMealId);
    if (existingIndex == -1) {
      favourites.add(
          DummyData().mealsData.firstWhere((meal) => meal.id == newMealId));
    } else {
      favourites.removeAt(existingIndex);
    }

    unawaited(saveFavourites(favourites).onError(
      (error, stackTrace) => print(stackTrace),
    ));
    emit(
      FavouritesLoaded(
        favouritedMeals: favourites,
      ),
    );   }

  Future<void> saveFavourites(List<Meal> favouritedList) async {
    favourites = favouritedList;
    await _prefs?.setString(favouriteDataPref, mealExtToJson(favouritedList));   }

  loadSavedFavourites(SharedPreferences prefs) async {
    String? favouritedList = prefs.getString(favouriteDataPref);
    try {
      if (favouritedList != null) {
        List<Meal> savedFavs = mealExtFromJson(favouritedList);
        favourites = savedFavs;
        return;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }   } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can encode response using:

List<Meal> mealExtFromJson=[];
String jsonString = json.encode(mealExtFromJson);

Using shared_preferences you can store string:
pref.setString(key, jsonString);

To access stored jsonString you can decode using:
List res = json.decode(pref.getString(key));
```

Comment: So how do I convert the list to map i.e List<Meals> favouriteMeals = [ ]; to map. I have enum data types

Comment: i have edited my answere. Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't access the result . List dynamic can't be assigned to the type string.

Comment: you have to parse json using model.fromJson(res) 
something like that.